# Is it possible to connect to my education onedrive with nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 21.04, online-accounts

I currently use an email issued by my university(it is the typical "edu" account) but, every time I tried to use the settings app to connect to my microsoft account I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z61QC.png). I have no problems with my google accounts and they do reflect accordingly in nautilus. I just want the same experience for my onedrive as well as I like the convenience of using my own file manager to manage onedrive.

Comment: PopOS isn't Ubuntu and is not supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: The best is using onedriver (it has a GUI). It's perfect. https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

There are only 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux:

- Via the OneDrive for Linux client - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free
- Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free
- Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free
- Via 'insync', 'ExpanDrive' - non-free client
- Via the web browser of your choice

Comment: to my view, onedriver is the best because it doesn't have the need to download the files. It justs download them when needed. It doesn't occupy space.